# Banner Image Placement and Proportion

Tags: html, css, header, banner

I am working on a project and for some reason I cannot get the banner placed in the position I want. There is code I am looking at hat has it set how I want to be:

HTML:

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Title</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="container">

                <header>
                    <h1>
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                            <!--<div>-->
                                They're Animals
                            <!--</div>-->
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                </header>



            </div><!--.container-->
            </body>
            </html>
```

and the CSS that works for my ideal banner is:

```
            /*  *************************************
                Base
                ************************************* */
            body { 
                background-color: #dfeff0;
                color: #333333;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            header a { color: #ad235e;}
            header a:hover { color: #000000;}
            h1 {
                color: #ad235e;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            h1 a:hover img { opacity: 0.7;}


            /*  *************************************
                Modules
                ************************************* */
            .container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 90%;
                max-width: 960px;
                position: relative;
            }
```

I have tried copying the CSS to put in my project (and the html) and it still does not work.

With actual text and more information in there it flows perfectly.

I guess something that might be more helpful is the code I have tried on my own:

```
            <!doctype html>

                <html lang="en">

                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>Title</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
                </head>

                <div class="container">

                <header>
                    <h1>
                      <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner">
                        <!--<body background="images/banner.png" alt="banner" >-->
                        Home Page
                    </h1>

                </header>

                </div>
```

and my attempt at CSS:

```
            h1
                {
                text-decoration:underline;
                text-align:center;

                }

            h1 img
                {
                height: 40%;
                width: 40%;
                margin: 0px 10px;
                padding: 5px;
                float: left;
                }
            .container
                {
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 960px;
                margin:0px auto;
                }
```

I guess the simplest way to put this is I am trying to get my banner to be an appropriate size (though I can manage that by editing the width and height) to the left of my h1 without pushing everything making it seem that it is "alone".

[image: This is what I would like my header to look like (the logo right next to the title without it pushing the content away]

[image: With my content on my page, this is how it actually looks.]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want to do. But I am guessing as you are using **float:left** you are maybe facing problem with the class "container".

I believe you can add one line in your .container CSS and fix the problem.

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but that is not quite what I am looking for. I am going to try and put pictures to help visualize what I am looking for.